# What is the distribution of the major ions across a neuronal membrane for a human neuron?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology

I have searched for the ion distributions across the membrane of human neurons on the internet but almost all the information refers to the giant axon of the squid. Could anyone give me the ion distribution across the membrane of a human neuron?

Comment: Have you tried Guyton-Hall physiology?